# System Document Management in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

The problem I'm having right now is that I want to create a business document management system using tables and columns like this on SharePoint

[image]

but I can't find any documentation about it or how to create it.

I would be really grateful if you could show me how to create it and whether I could create such a document management system on SharePoint Online.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we could implement this in SharePoint - in fact, SharePoint is made for that, one of the best document management systems. However, if you are from other document management systems and migrating to SharePoint, then you should be familiar with SharePoint UI and navigation - how actually this works because we should not compare the non-SharePoint document management system with SharePoint.

For your scenario, we can create a site along with the document library (in fact you can use the default "Documents" library). Then create all the above-mentioned document metadata as site columns and attached these into a content type, then finally add that content type to document library.

Finally, you can migrate your documents from the legacy system that you are using at present - most probably you can use any free version of thrid party migration tool like **Microsoft Migration tool**, **ShareGate**, **Metalogix**, **FME** Migration Center.

**Note**:

- From the above-listed migration tool, **FME** tool only supports migration
  from non-SharePoint to SharePoint.
- If you few documents you can manually upload by drag and drop
  features or even you opt for custom PowerShell script ( if you google it, you will get a lot of scripts available).
- Based on the metadata you can create multiple views, groups for the business needs.

When it comes to the search or filter of the document, at the top of the document library you will get search box which will accept any input from the given metadata columns - you can search with any of them.

As an alternate, if you want to have similar kind of (as mentioned in your screenshot) filter UI - you can go with the **Metadata Navigation and Filtering** but in this, your metadata column type should be managed metadata - then you can filter the data similar to above what you have at present - below is the simimalr example from SharePoint:

[image: Manage Metadata Navigation]

Reference URL:

To configure the metadata navigation for a list or library, you may refer to the below article:

[Configure metadata navigation for a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-a8ddfcd1-a486-4e0f-b1b1-f10ca79fa9bc)

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot

Comment: @Daniel Tran : I am glad to hear that it helped you, could you please mark as answer if this answered your question it will help to the upcoming visitors... thank you :-)